# Reverting changes in only one file via GIT

Tags: git, version-control

I have a templates directory with around 10 *.html files. 
I made changes to most of them. 
Now i want to revert changes only in the index.html file. 
How can i do that:

if i have committed my latest changes?
if i have not committed my latest changes?
(i dont want to `git reset --HARD` which will undo all the changes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
git checkout -- index.html
```

for when you haven't committed yet.

If you have committed you need to `git reset [--mixed]` the last commit, do the `git checkout` and `git commit` again.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't committed:

```
git checkout index.html
```

If you have committed, use `git log` to find the commit id you wish to revert, such as `3a765c6cd6316a665cca789d11a7186234c203a8` and type:

```
git checkout 3a765c6cd6316a665cca789d11a7186234c203a8 -- index.html
```